# Connect Azure Application Insights with Zendesk

Tags: angular, azure, azure-application-insights, zendesk, zendesk-api

Our webapps use Application Insights for logging technical issues and Zendesk for maintaining tickets of our customers.

We would like to have an automated way that when there are errors, such as certain HTTP errors, we use the Zendesk API to create a ticket in our system, so the business side that maintain Zendesk is instantly aware of certain issues in certain webapps.

Is this possible somehow? We are already using the Zendesk API in our webapps, but it would be better if this connection is set up on the Azure side, so Application Insights of that webapp sends a message using the Zendesk API to automatically create a ticket about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to integrate Application insights with Zendesk API.
Lucky for you there are few solutions to achieve that.
Azure has few connectors to work with Zendesk API and you can choose which one works best for you.
I think the least effort would be to setup logic app that would pull data from App Insights and create new ticket for you in Zendesk API.

You may learn more about it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/zendesk/